# How can I fix missing documentation for an enum when using pest?

Tags: parsing, rust, documentation, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I use the pest parser to parse my input, but it always gives me two "missing documentation" warnings:

```rust
#[allow(missing_copy_implementations, missing_docs)]
#[derive(Parser, Debug, Clone)]
#[grammar = "grammar.pest"]
pub struct MyParser;
```

leads to:

```
warning: missing documentation for an enum
  --> src/lib.rs:76:10
   |
76 | #[derive(Parser, Debug, Clone)]
   |          ^^^^^^
   |
note: the lint level is defined here
  --> src/lib.rs:7:5
   |
7  |     missing_docs,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: this warning originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

warning: missing documentation for a variant
  --> src/lib.rs:76:10
   |
76 | #[derive(Parser, Debug, Clone)]
   |          ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this warning originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

warning: 2 warnings emitted
```

How can I fix that? Only the struct should have documentation, the enum should be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derive macros can choose to copy attributes when they generate new types -- so in theory Pest could copy over your `#[allow(missing_docs)]` directive to the enum it's generating (or copy over the documentation itself). Without Pest adding this feature, your only option to suppress this warning is to put `#![allow(missing_docs)]` at the top of the file.